# In what condition that uniformly convergence of functions can imply derivative convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Let $f_n$: $(0,1)\to (0,1)$ be given, where $f_n$ is a.e. differentiable, absolutely continuous, and monotone increasing. Suppose $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Then would it implies that $f_n'\to f'$ a.e.?

I know generally uniformly convergence has no way to imply convergence of derivative, but I somehow remembered that monotone increasing would help, but I can't recall where I saw this statement.

---

PS: I also have $f_n'$ are uniformly bounded (but may not continuous). So I think my statement should hold, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sketchy Proof: By absolute continuity, we have
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = f_n(a) + \int^x_a f'_n(t)\ dt
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(a) +\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^x_a f_n'(t)\ dt \\
\Rightarrow &\ \  f(x) = f(a) +\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int^x_a f'_n(t)\ dt. 
\end{align}
Hence if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n'(t)$ converges pointwise to some function $g$, then you can show that
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(a) +\int^x_a g(t)\ dt \ \ a.e.
\end{align} 
which means $f$ is absolutely continuous and
\begin{align}
f'(x) = g(x) \ \ a. e.
\end{align}
However, if we don't know apriori that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n'(t)$ exist, then we might not be able to conclude anything. Think [construction of Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Iterative_construction).

Answer (score 1):

Consider for any interval $I\subset (0,1)$ the function
$f_I$ which is zero before $I$, grows linearly with derivative one in $I$, and then is constant. Consider the sequence of intervals obtained considering for every $n\in \mathbb N$ the intervals $(k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n)$ for $k=0,...,2^n-1$. The sequence of the related functions $f_I$ satisfies the properties and converges uniformly to zero, but the derivative has nowhere limit.

Comment: Thank you sir, but my function has uniformly bounded derivative

Comment: @JumpJump they have all derivative at most 1

Comment: I see. My bad, understand.

Comment: So I need to know apriori that $f_n'$ converge a.e. as @Jacky Chong comment above.

Comment: @Jumpjump Yes, exactly. I put this example to show the necessity of such assumption, because the proposed cantor approximating functions do not have bounded derivatives

Comment: @Jumpjump Also, without that requirement it is false even up to subsequence. You can take a sequence of functions whose derivatives assume only the values 0 and 2, alternating the two values on smaller and smaller scale, that uniformly approximate the function $f (x)=x$